# C++: Abstract classes inheritance and construction

Tags: c++, class, constructor, abstract-class

I need to build a C++ program the does function composition of 2 objects.
The objects can be either a polynome, a rational function or a composed function.

I have an abstract class named 'func'. I also have 2 classes that inherited 'func', named 'ratfunc'and 'polynom'.
A third class 'compfunc', also inherits 'func' and it's constructor header is given to me.
Comfunc receives 2 abstract objects from the 'func' class (by reference) and needs to compose a new function out of them (syntax: new compfunc(*outer,*inner). outer,inner are *func)

Outter and inner can be either ratfunc, polynome, or comfunc itself.

My question is how can I build a constructor like this WITHOUT using templates and without knowing the objects classes.

**EDIT:**

The code:

Main:

```
  func* outer;
  func* inner;
  char* outer_name = strtok(func_value, ",");
  char* inner_name = strtok(NULL, ","); 
  try{
       outer = func_list.at(outer_name);
       inner = func_list.at(inner_name);
       func_list[string(outer_name)+"("+string(inner_name)+")"]=new 
       compfunc(*outer,*inner);
      }
```

Func class (Abstract):

```
class func {
 public: 
func(); //constructor
func(const func& f); //copy constructor
virtual ~func(); 

protected:
bool flag; //values has been assigned, initialised to false in the constructor 
};
```

Polynom class:

```
class polynom : public func {
public:
polynom(); //default constructor 
polynom(int n, int* coefs); //constructor
polynom(const polynom& pol); //copy constructor
~polynom(); //destrcutor
 protected:
int n_; //order of the polynom
int* coefs_; //coefficients 
 };
```

Ratfunc class:

```
class ratfunc : public func{
public:
ratfunc(const polynom& p, const polynom& q); //constructor
ratfunc(const ratfunc& rf); //copy constructor
~ratfunc(); //desctrcutor
protected:
polynom p_; //down
polynom q_; //up 
 };
```

Compfunc:

```
class compfunc : public func{
public:
compfunc(const func& outter, const func& inner); 
compfunc(const compfunc& cf); //copy constructor
~compfunc(); //destrcutor
 protected:
func* outer_; 
func* inner_; 
};
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It's much shorter and much clearer to just post a small example of the code you are describing than it is to try to describe your code.

Comment: ^ this and you dont say how the two functions are supposed to be composed. Should it be `compfunc(x) = outer(inner(x))` ?

Comment: I added the relevant pieces of the code. Thanks

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. It is rather hard to make any sense out of the fragment you show.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have any user-defined constructors in `func`. It does however make a lot of sense to have at least one more virtual function there. It would be rather impossible to accomplish your task without one.

Comment: Edited one more time

Comment: Still makes no sense. What does your `function` class **do**?

Comment: @n.m. nothing. It's there because he's using type erasure.

Comment: @Whatever Huh? No. *Because* of type erasure the class **must** do something, otherwise it is totally useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing the classes by const reference, I assume you want to copy them. For that you will need additional virtual member function `clone` which will return a pointer to a dynamically allocated copy of the object.

```cpp
class func {
    ...
    virtual func* clone() const;
    ...
};

class polynom: public func {
    ...
    virtual polynom* clone() const override {
        return new polynom(n_, coefs_);
    }
    ...
};

class compfunc: public func {
    ...
    compfunc(const func& outter, const func& inner): outer_(outter.clone()), inner_(inner.clone()) {}
    ...
    virtual compfunc* clone() const override {
        ...
    }
};
```

This way you can copy the passed objects regardless of their dynamic type.

Comment: "Because you are passing the classes by const reference, I assume you want to copy them". That's a non sequitur if I ever saw one.